# see if a variable equals any other variables in a list php

Tags: php, arrays, search

In php, I was wondering how I check if a variable equals any of the variables in a list.

I thought I could try something like

```
if( $example == array($one, $two, $three, $four, $five) ) {
    //code here
}
```

This didn't work, is there a similar way of doing it? Otherwise, what would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you mean something like [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function?

```
if( in_array($example, array($one, $two, $three, $four, $five)) ) {
    //code here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
$array = array($one, $two, $three, $four, $five);
$example = 'somestring';
if(in_array($example, $array)){
    //code here
}
```

or if you want to check with strict eg `===` not `==`

```
if(in_array($example, $array, true)){
    //code here
}
```

Comment: darn, should have thought about in_array() ...so obvious

Comment: @hurrtz yours should work as well and might be better in some situations, but `in_array()` is probably better for what OP is looking for.

Comment: Hello, thank you for such quick feedback. If you don't mind, it doesn't seem to be recognizing that the if statement is an actual statement, because it is giving an error for the "unexpected '{'" right after it. Maybe you know why?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add an extra `)` before `{` my code above has been updated

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array($one, $two, $three, $four, $five);

foreach ($array as $value) {
    if ($example === $value) {
        something;
    }
}
```