# PHP If a variable equals this or this

Tags: php

I have this if statement in my PHP:

```
if($_SESSION['usrName']!='test1'){
    header('location:login.php');
}
```

But i want it to be something like this:

```
if($_SESSION['usrName']!='test1' or 'user'){
    header('location:login.php');
}
```

But i cant figure out how to do it in PHP code. I have tried this:

```
if($_SESSION['usrName']!='test1','user'){
    header('location:login.php');
}
```

And this:

```
if(($_SESSION['usrName']!='test1')||($_SESSION['usrName']!='user')){
    header('location:login.php');
}
```

Can anybody help please?

Comment: Your last attempt is correct.

Comment: @Brad Not really, as it would need to be && to get the right result

Comment: @Brad Actually is not correct as it would always evaluate to TRUE with the OR condition.  Any given string will ALWAYS be not equal to `test1` OR not equal to `user`.

Comment: I'm guessing Brad (and his upvoters) thought it was `==`, as testing `!=` a specific username in code is a rather unusual thing to do.  I had to look again myself.

Comment: By the way guys i am having the if statement check if the usernames are not equal to the specified because i only want the specified users to be adble to access the page but for the others to be redirected to another page.

Comment: @MikeBrant Good point.  I only looked at syntax.

Comment: May or may not be easy to implement depending on your objectives, but I would recommend putting your log in as the else condition. Else can be sort of a default fail over condition, and in the case of a log in you'd probably want your code to fail towards requiring log in than fail towards allowing people in. (Of course the best case is for the code not to break, but it never hurts to be prepared.)     

if (
$_SESSION['usrName] == 'user' || $_SESSION['usrName'] == 'test1'
) {
    header('location:XXXXX');
} else {header('location:login.php');
 }

Comment: @lostphilosopher Now you've got `||` and `&&` mixed up the other way...

Comment: @StephenTG, yep, I typed too fast. I fixed it as soon as I posted, but you were even quicker on the draw. (Insert chest clutch and death rattle.) Anyway +1

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775565/see-if-a-variable-equals-any-other-variables-in-a-list-php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to replace the `||` with `&&`. Because you only want to redirect when both conditions are true.

```
if(($_SESSION['usrName']!='test1') && ($_SESSION['usrName']!='user')){
    header('location:login.php');
}
```

Comment: @Danbyization: This is great. When the timer of 15 minutes is up it would be great if you mark one of the many correct answers as the right one.

Answer (score 9):

```
if (!in_array($_SESSION['usrName'], array('test1', 'user')) {
    header('location:login.php');
}
```

This checks if variable $_SESSION['usrName'] is not in list of strings to simplify additional allowed user.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvotes - it may not be very efficient, but it will have the effect of checking that the session variable is not equal to either of the test strings.

Comment: I was one of the downvotes - and it was because there was no attempt to point out what was different or actually explain the answer.

Comment: @jcsanyi That's a fair reason I suppose. Although it could be considered hypocritical that you didn't explain your downvote to help Faisal improve their answer.

Comment: I agree I probably should be more proactive in asking users to improve their answers. When faced with a wall of similar answers though, I find that it helps to find the better answers when those that are just code are moved to the bottom. I do try to remember to check back and remove the downvote if the answer has been improved (as I did in this case).

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, you need to be careful with your boolean logic - `(NOT X) || (NOT Y)` is equivalent to `NOT (X AND Y)`, whereas what you want is `NOT (X OR Y)` which is equivalent to `(NOT X) AND (NOT Y)`.

For this particular situation, there are also a couple of other options, although none as neat as the invalid syntaxes you tried.

First, there is `in_array()`, which is easy to read, but not very efficient if you use it a lot with long lists (for a simple case like this, it's not worth worrying about performance, though):

```
$allowed_users = array('test1', 'user');
if ( ! in_array($_SESSION['usrName'], $allowed_users ) { ... }
```

Or, you can build a hash with the usernames as *keys*; this is more efficient as the list grows, because PHP can check for a key without looping through the whole list:

```
$allowed_users = array('test1' => true, 'user' => true);
if ( ! array_key_exists($_SESSION['usrName'], $allowed_users) ) { ... }
// Or, if you don't mind PHP raising a few notices about accessing undefined keys
if ( ! $allowed_user[ $_SESSION['usrName'] ] ) { ... }
```

Finally, you can use a `switch` statement, with the labels falling through, and a `default` case acting as the "else":

```
switch ( $_SESSION['usrName'] )
{
    case 'test1':
    case 'user':
        // These users are allowed :)
    break;
    default:
        header('location:login.php');
}
```

Which, if any, of these you choose to use will depend on how you expect the code to grow in future, but they're useful tricks to know.

Comment: +1 for a very thorough explanation and list of options. I particularly liked the summary of boolean negatives at the beginning.

Comment: It's amazing how often a proper understanding of boolean algebra comes in handy. I've even been known to scribble Karnaugh maps when planning a piece of PHP code...

Answer (score 2):

Your last attempt is almost correct.

However...

```
if (var != something || var != something-else)
```

...will always be true, because one of those conditions will always match. Even if it's equal to one side, it won't be equal to the other.

When you're testing two negatives like that, you need to use AND (`&&`) instead of OR (`||`).

```
if (($_SESSION['usrName']!='test1') && ($_SESSION['usrName']!='user'))
```

This will match if it's not equal to one, **and also** not equal to the other.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like:

```
if($_SESSION['usrName'] != 'test1' and $_SESSION['usrName'] != 'user'){
    header('location:login.php');
}
```

The first attempt of yours is equivalent to:

```
if(($_SESSION['usrName']!='test1') or 'user'){
    header('location:login.php');
}
```

Second seems like invalid syntax

Third is almost right, you just need to replace `||` with `and` or `&&`, as anything will be unequal to either 'user' or 'test1'

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you're checking if either one of conditions are true. The last condition will evaluate to true if either one of the conditions are correct. I assume you're trying to check if *both* the the conditions are true. In that case, you'll need `&&` instead of `||`.

Try:

```
if( ($_SESSION['usrName'] != 'test1') && ($_SESSION['usrName'] != 'user') ) {
    header('location:login.php');
}
```