# PHP Ternary Operator Misunderstanding?

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I'm not sure whether what I'm doing is fundamentally wrong or whether I've just had a long day and am missing something obvious...

I'm setting array values dynamically like so:

```
$criteria = array(
    'is_blue' => get_color($color_1) == ('Dark Blue' OR 'Light Blue') ? TRUE : FALSE,
    'is_red'  => get_color($color_2) == ('Dark Red' OR 'Light Red') ? TRUE : FALSE
);
```

When I try the following line just run by itself:

```
echo get_color($color_1);
```

I get `Dark Green`. So you would expect it to evaluate as `FALSE` in `$criteria['is_blue']`.

But - `$criteria['is_blue']` is `TRUE`.

Why is this? Am I misunderstanding the Ternary operator?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the ternary operator correctly, but the `if` portion is malformed.

You are essentially testing if `get_color($color_1)` is equal to `true` because `'Dark Blue' OR 'Light Blue'` equals `true`.

You'll need to test each value independantly, like this:

```
$criteria = array(
    'is_blue' => get_color($color_1) == 'Dark Blue' OR get_color($color_1) == 'Light Blue' ? true : false,
    'is_red'  => get_color($color_2) == 'Dark Red' OR get_color($color_2) == 'Light Red' ? true : false
);
```

Comment: Aha - got it. It's a shame there's not a more elegant way of typing that in PHP, but never mind - thanks.

Comment: See the answer by @Cole. Much more readable, elegant and expandable :)

Comment: This technique is in no way advisable.  Not only is long-winded, it is potentially forcing php to call the same function with the same parameter more than once <-- bad coding practice.

Comment: This answer addresses the OP's original code specifically. For a different method, see [Cole's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20573430/924299) or the [linked similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775565/see-if-a-variable-equals-any-other-variables-in-a-list-php).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with the ('Dark Blue' OR 'Light Blue') part. You could rewrite this to use in_array...

```
'is_blue' => in_array(get_color($color_1), array(('Dark Blue','Light Blue'))
```

Also, you don't ternary to return `true` or `false` as that is naturally returned by `in_array` already.

http://www.php.net/in_array

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you have is that ('Dark Blue' OR 'Light Blue') is a boolean (true or false)

You need to use the equality twice:

```
$criteria = array(
    'is_blue' => get_color($color_1) == 'Dark Blue' OR get_color($color_1) == 'Light Blue' ? TRUE : FALSE,
    'is_red'  => get_color($color_2) == 'Dark Red' OR get_color($color_2) == 'Light Red' ? TRUE : FALSE
);
```

also ternary operator is redundant in that case, you can use:

```
$criteria = array(
    'is_blue' => get_color($color_1) == 'Dark Blue' OR get_color($color_1) == 'Light Blue',
    'is_red'  => get_color($color_2) == 'Dark Red' OR get_color($color_2) == 'Light Red'
);
```

$criteria['is_blue'] and $criteria['is_red'] will have the boolean value that you want.

I hope I have helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$criteria = array(
    'is_blue' => (get_color($color_1) == 'Dark Blue' OR get_color($color_1) == 'Light Blue') ? TRUE : FALSE,
    'is_red'  => (get_color($color_2) == 'Dark Red' OR get_color($color_2) == 'Light Red') ? TRUE : FALSE
);
```

Each comparison in if needs to be independent